# Laravel Nova data duplicated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

this is my first time using laravel nova, i want to save my data in 2 table, the first save basic data and the second save history data. In my Item table i'm saving id, code, name, price and my Item_Codes table saving item_id and code, i got it. My problem is when save the data in Item_Codes is saving two times

I'm using Laravel Observer, this is my saved function of ItemObserver

```
public function saved(Item $item)
{
    DB::table('item_codes')->insert(
        [
            'item_id' => $item->id,
            'code' => $item->current_code,
            'created_by' => $item->created_by,
        ]
    );
}
```

and this is my Item Resource

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        Text::make('Original code', 'original_code')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'string', 'max:255')
            ->hideFromIndex(),

        Text::make('Current code', 'current_code')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'string', 'max:255'),

        Text::make('Name', 'name')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'string', 'max:255'),

        Textarea::make('Description', 'description')
            ->rules('required')
            ->creationRules('required', 'string'),

        Number::make('Cost', 'cost')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required')
            ->min(1),

        Number::make('Minimum price', 'minimum_price')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required')
            ->min(1),

        Text::make('ABCD Classification', 'abcd_classification')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'string')
            ->hideFromIndex()
            ->hideWhenCreating()
            ->hideWhenUpdating(),

        BelongsToMany::make('Categories'),

        new Panel('Stock', $this->stockFields()),
        new Panel('Tracking', $this->trackingFields()),
    ];
}
```

This is my Item Model

```
class Item extends Model{

/**
 * The attributes that aren mass assignable.
 * 
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'original_code',
    'current_code',
    'name',
    'description',
    'current_stock',
    'unavailable_stock',
    'cost',
    'minimum_price',
    'abcd_classification'
];

/**
 * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
 * 
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = [
    'created_by',
    'updated_by'
];

/**
 * 
 * Providers
 * 
 * Returns the items providers
 * 
 * @return collection
 */
public function providers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Provider');
}

/**
 * 
 * Categories
 * 
 * Returns the items categories
 * 
 * @return collection
 */
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category');
}
}
```

Sorry for my bad english, i hope your answers

Comment: Do you want to do that on creating, updating or both?

Comment: i just want that when i'm saving a item in my items_tables this will save in item_codes too

Comment: Thing is that `saved` method is invoked on both: `created` and `updated`. I would suspect on something around that first. If you need it only when object is created, put it in body of method `created` not saved.

Comment: I tried to used `created` method and this was saved two time too

Comment: It is triggered twice somewhere in application. Double check code base (of code you wrote). Do you use some event/listener pairs? Maybe there?

Comment: I do not have more triggered and no, i am using a function for save the item and observer function for save item_codes

Comment: That code with field method doesn't tell much. Show the code where you make insert (possibly conroller).

Comment: The code where i am insert the item is fields function, because i am working with laravel nova

Comment: I think you should also ask somewhere on Nova forums or something similar. Maybe to contact support since it is enterprise paid variant, they will be glad to help you I am sure. I gave my best shot, but I am not sure about presented code there. :/

Comment: I had this same issue. On clicking create, it would insert twice. Which browser are you using. I switched to Chrome and didn't have this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't duplicate calling the `Observer` in `AppServiceProvider` and `NovaServiceProvider`.

You should call it only once in `NovaServiceProvider`.